# CodeIgniter/TankAuth forgot_password function sending emails with no content

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, postfix-mta

Recently moved an existing CodeIgniter product to its own VPS, everything is working away. However, for some reason a password has been invalidated and when the forgot_password function is run the email arrives with an intact subject line, however, the emails have no content. At all. This is the offending code:

```
function _send_email($type, $email, &$data) {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject(sprintf($this->lang->line('auth_subject_' . $type), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth')));
        $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/' . $type . '-html', $data, TRUE));

    echo $this->load->view('email/' . $type . '-html', $data, TRUE);

        $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/' . $type . '-txt', $data, TRUE));
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

I wrote a short PHP script to send an email using the same CodeIgniter library:

```
<?php
```

if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
class EmailTest extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    }

    function sendTest(){
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        //$this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));


        $this->email->to('cameron.j.leafe@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject("Here and There");
        $this->email->message("I hear you are an example");
        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
?>
```

That email lands completely fine, and produces this output:

```
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 18:55:55 +1000
From: "EPI Dashboard" <epi@epidashboard.com>
Return-Path: <epi@epidashboard.com>
Reply-To: "epi@epidashboard.com" <epi@epidashboard.com>
X-Sender: epi@epidashboard.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <534ba29b87010@epidashboard.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_534ba29b8708b"


=?utf-8?Q?Here_and_There?=
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_534ba29b8708b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

I hear you are an example


--B_ALT_534ba29b8708b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

I hear you are an example

--B_ALT_534ba29b8708b--
```

The server is a CentOS 6 VPS running postfix and obviously PHP/MySql/Apache.

Any thoughts on what to check or any resources that you can think of would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP.INI file for this server need to have the line:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Which fixed the problem instantly. Not entirely sure as to why parts of the email were showing up and not the body, but it works.